# Fixed menu. Problems when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, I'm spanish, so I'm sorry for my english, it's not the best...
I'm having some problems in a fixed nav I wanted to do in a web page I'm developing...
I've made it with CSS3 and jQuery...
When I scroll down some px's, my nav receives a name class with some attributes...

The problem is that when I scroll down, the nav doesnt move; only when I reload the page or even when I open the F12 menu...
So, if you can help me, I would be so pleased...
This is the code:

/* HTML5 */

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="principal">
            <header>
                <p>tapeHD</p>
                <hr/>
                <span>Enero 17, 2015</span>
            </header>
            <section>
                <video autoplay loop muted volume="0" id="video_index">
                    <source src="videos/index.webm" type="video/webm" />
                    <source src="videos/index.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    <source src="videos/index.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
                </video>

                <div id="comenzar">
                    <h2 class="primero">Comparte videos con más</h2>
                    <h2 class="segundo">de un <span>millón</span> de personas</h2>
                    <input type="submit" value="Comenzar ahora" id="boton_comenzar" />
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

        <div id="pagina">
            <header id="cabecera">
                <div id="cabecera_menu">
                    <div id="apartado_logo"><div id="tapeHD"><a href="#"><p>tapeHD</p></a></div></div>
                    <div id="busqueda"><input type="search" id="buscar" placeholder="Buscar" value="" /></div>
                    <!-- Este div se hace visible una vez el usuario está logeado... -->
                    <div id="usuario">
                        <input type="submit" id="iniciar" value="Iniciar sesión" />
                        <div id="imagen_perfil">
                            <div id="esfera"><img src="images/user.jpg" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="menu_usuario">
                    <a id="boton_menu" class=""><span></span></a>
                    <nav id="opciones">
                        <li id="perfil" class=""><a></a></li>
                        <li id="ajustes" class=""><a></a></li>
                        <input type="submit" id="desconectar" class="" value="" />
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section>
                <div id="contenido"></div>
                <div id="menu">
                    <div id="info">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>Etiquetas
                                <li><a href="#">Animales</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Deportes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Comedia</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Juegos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Terror</a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <ul>Sobre nosotros
                                <li><a href="#">Quiénes somos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div id="social">
                        <nav>
                            <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                            <img src="images/social/facebook.png" /></a></li>

                            <li class="twitter"><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">
                            <img src="images/social/twitter.png" /></a></li>

                            <li class="google"><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/">
                            <img src="images/social/google.png" /></a></li>

                            <li class="pinterest"><a target="_blank" href="https://es.pinterest.com/">
                            <img src="images/social/pinterest.png" /></a></li>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <div id="banner">
                    <h2>¿Tienes más dudas?</h2>
                    <p>Póngase en contacto con nuestro personal técnico</p>
                    <div id="personal">
                        <div class="coder"><img src="images/Antonio.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="coder"><img src="images/Antonio.jpg" /></div>
                        <div class="coder"><img src="images/Antonio.jpg" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="copyright">
                    <p><span>Copyright© 2015:</span> Todos los derechos reservados</p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

/* CSS3 */

```
#pagina header {
    background-color: #111;
    height: 161px;
    width: 100%;
}

#pagina header.fixed-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

/* JQuery */

```
    jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $("#cabecera");
    var position = nav.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > position) {
            nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle from the problem. That's easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to add these styles to your fixed element:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /*For -webkit- browsers such as Google Chrome or Safari*/
-moz-transform:translateZ(0); /* For -moz- browsers such as Firefox */
-o-transform:translateZ(0); /* For -o- browsers such as Opera */
transform:translateZ(0); /* General style for Internet Explorer */
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you ^^

Comment: What I dont understand is... why do you have to put that attribute? In firefox and safari, it works without it

Comment: There isn't a whole lot of information about the transform: translateZ and why it fixes this issue, but my guess is that Firefox and Safari handle the Position fixed correctly, when Chrome doesn't, transform is normally used to transform things, but I guess that translateZ forces Chrome to re-position the element with the given margins from the top, applying -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); on a menu with text makes the text have a padding of 0, applying 100 instead of 0 fixes the text but breaks the position fixed

Answer (score 0):

When I load this into a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xc3t6sxu/ - there are some issues with it jumping around when you scroll, which is being caused because `position: fixed` takes it out of the flow of the document, which is resizing the page and making it so you are no longer scrolled below the threshold. If I add a `position: absolute` style to `#pagina header`, as per http://jsfiddle.net/xc3t6sxu/1/ it seems to work for me, although you will need to add a margin to the top of your `section` to stop it from initially overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to be grater or equal than. That could help:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= position) {
    nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
} else {
    nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
}
```